# Convert NA in "" values

Tags: static

I´m trying to convert NA values into blank values but without missing any of the rows. Using this code:

```
Data[is.na(Data)] <- ""
```

But it brings me this alert:

```
Error: Assigned data `""` must be compatible with existing data.  
Error occurred for column `Grupo_empresarial_cód`. 
Can't convert <character> to <double>.
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In what language/environment?

Comment: When asking a question related to code, it is always necessary to add a tag for the specific programming language you're using. Please [edit] your question to add that tag so that we can try to help.